# Variable box is not available

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, bookmarks

[My bookmarked query does not have a variable box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVQKx.png)
[I saw a video and the variable box is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqx6J.png)

I am a week old with phpmyadmin.

I created a SQL query and save it as a bookmark and with `/* where make = '[variable]' */` in a simple SQL query.

After saving and execute the SQL, I receive 25 rows, so everything is ok. I return to the SQL query and drop down the bookmark, so I select my saved query, but the variable box is not available for me to enter the make of the product.

```
phpMyAdmin - 4.8.3
MySQL - 5.6.4
Apache - 2.4.34
```

What did I not do right or is it something I didn't understand correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/bookmarks.html) the proper syntax would be to enumerate your variable, so this should work:

```
/* WHERE make = '[VARIABLE1]' */
```